# Math object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, math, constructor, capitalization

In JavaScript, Math object doesn't have an constructor, but why it's capitalized such as Math.random()?
As I have understood, objects such as Date and Object get capitalized because they have constructors (e.g. Date.now())

Comment: covered in the docs [Math](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) >Unlike many other global objects, Math is not a constructor. All properties and methods of Math are static. You refer to the constant pi as Math.PI and you call the sine function as Math.sin(x), where x is the method’s argument. Constants are defined with the full precision of real numbers in JavaScript.

Comment: @pilchard That... does nothing to explain why it's capitalised.

Comment: It is capitalised because it is a built-in **object**.  Many built-in objects have constructors - some don't, like `Infinity`  [Built-in objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects)

Comment: Case is just a convention, Math has been around for a long time, so I would say it's for legacy reasons.  But technically I agree it really should me `math.sin()` etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initial caps capitalization isn't *only* used for constructor functions, though that's the predominant use. It's also used for objects like `Math` and `Reflect`, values like `Infinity`, and the `Symbol` function (`Symbol` creates symbols, but isn't a constructor — you don't use `new` with it). It differentiates them from local variables.

A lot of this was put together in a frenzied 10 days in May in 1995 by Brendan Eich, who probably didn't worry too much about what he was and wasn't capitalizing given the deadline he was working to. :-)

(There's an argument that `Infinity` and `NaN` should be `infinity` and `nan` to match `undefined` and `null`, but...consistency is hard. Then there's the whole thing that `Infinity`, `NaN`, and `undefined` are global constants but `null` is a keyword...)